# Option-Left/Right Arrow doesn't work

Tags: macos, shortcut

The keyboard shortcuts Option-Left/Right Arrow is made for moving the cursor by words, as Apple described here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 , but doesn't work on my MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010, OS X 10.11). They fail to work everywhere I can try, including but not limited to Notes, TextEdit, Mail, Google.com search field and iMessage text field. Meanwhile on my friend's MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013, OS X 10.11), they work damn well! Anyone can help?

Note:

1. An Apple Wireless Keyboard is paired to my Mac, but it doesn't help.
2. System has been restarted several times, doesn't help.
3. Including Option-Delete and Option-Shift-Up Arrow, all the Option related shortcuts in the "Document shortcuts" session of https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 doesn't work.
4. The Option key is fine, I have tested it by shortcuts like Command-Optiono-H which works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem has been solved by switching the input source from "Unicode Hex Input" (my major input source) to "U.S.". I think some option based shortcuts can't function as usual with "Unicode Hex Input". You can update the input sources by searching "unicode" to be directed to system preferences -> Keyboard. Click "Input Sources" and remove other input methods that might be causing the error. Then open a new window for the program you want to test.

Comment: Do you know how to switch the input source?

Comment: To add to above answer. It wasn't sufficient to merely do the switch. At least on my system, I had to delete the Unicode Input sources as many applications were still defaulting to them.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem.
- I added a new Keyboard Input Source
- Made sure the Input Sources are shown in the Menu Bar
- Switched to a different Input Source
- Tested "option + Left/Right", works!
- Switched back to my original Input Source
- Tested "option + Left/Right", works!

Answer (score 3):

Another problem here can pop up if you have a gaming keyboard.  I have a `g/pc` button that is activated by `fn + f12` that turns this off.  I always forget about it and then remember when I visit this link, so dropping it in for next time :)

Comment: I appreciate this post, I always forget about the `g/pc` toggle. It causes such weird inconsistencies. For reference, my keyboard is the Max Keyboard Nighthawk-X7.

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem. Corsair Strave K70 MK2, I had the "lock" on.